# How to cut overlapping when save for web using artboards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, artboard, crop

How can I auto cut the overlapping stuff outside the artboard when I save for web and/or just while using "normal export"?

When I'm in the *save for web* window the image is bigger then the artboard size because of layers who are out of the artboard size. I'd like to auto cut all overlapping stuff when saving/exporting just like it was in CC 2015.0.0.

Like working without the artboard future.

I'm running version CC 2015.1.2

Comment: You may need to be specific about this "new version" (I don't have a new version) and as far as I'm aware what you want to do is how it should work. "new version" will also be pretty meaningless to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try File>Export>Export As...

That will save each artboard as their own file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have selected the "Clip to Artboard" option, in your Save for Web options.  Otherwise, Illustrator will automatically crop the output to your artwork's full dimensions.

[image]

Comment: The user might be talking about Adobe Photoshop CC since that tag is used.

Comment: @AndrewH didn't even catch that!  I still forget that PS even has artboards now.  I see "artboard" and instantly think AI.  I tried to replicate their error in PS and can't.  Mine is respecting my artboard and cropping the larger stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure to Select the Art-board and the Hit " Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S " for save for Web
 Or you could also do the normal export 
" File > Export > Export As "
Here you can select the Artboard you want from the left side. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a user slice around the size of your artboard, and in the "Save For Web" menu just save out "All User Slices" to trim and discard anything in the blank transparency. This also works with Animated GIFs!